# ListPicker SelectedIndex Not Shown Correctly in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a strange problem with the `ListPicker` element in WP7.

**The Problem**

Setting a `ListPicker`'s `SelectedIndex` via a `Binding` doesn't change the default item shown after it loads.

**Example**

As a test, I've quickly modified Microsoft's `SettingsSample` to include a `ListPicker`. You can download it at: http://www.mediafire.com/?w0n0ymkh4dwe9b3

This is our collapsed `ListPicker`:

```
 -----------------
| Times New Roman |
 -----------------
```

And this is `ListPicker` when it's expanded:

```
 -----------------
| Times New Roman |
| Arial           |
| Comic Sans MS   |
 -----------------
```

If we select 'Arial', navigate away, then come back again, the `ListPicker` still shows:

```
 -----------------
| Times New Roman |
 -----------------
```

Whereas it ought to show (because the settings are saved correctly):

```
 -----------------
| Arial           |
 -----------------
```

**Further Confusion**

In the above example, if we click on the `ListPicker`, 'Arial' is actually selected (because the text for this `ListBoxItem` is highlighted). For some reason, it's just not shown as the default value when the control is loaded.

If we forget about the `Binding` approach, and instead manually set `SelectedIndex` to '1' in XAML, then we get the expected result when the control is loaded:

```
 -----------------
| Arial           |
 -----------------
```

**Ideas?**

Is there a way to update the `ListPicker` control to show the `SelectedIndex` properly when using a `Binding`? I guess I'm missing something obvious, but I've searched and not been able to find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is an outstanding bug with the ListPicker control to do with binding the selection. I think the recommended solution is to manually set a binding in the `OnNavigatedTo` override for the page. The following code shows how I do it for one of my apps:

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            Binding pickerBinding = new Binding("DistanceUnit")
            {
                Source = App.Current.Resources["Settings"],
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
            };
            this._distanceUnit.SetBinding(ListPicker.SelectedItemProperty, pickerBinding);
        }
```

Alternatively, you can handle the **Loaded** event for the ListPicker itself and set the binding there. The previous approach is ideal if you have multiple pickers. The latter approach is more suited to the scenario when you just have a single picker.

**NOTE:** I haven't checked the latest source code for the Toolkit to see if this is still an outstanding bug.

Comment: Thanks Derek, that's perfect! After checking, you're right that there is a bug with the `ListPicker`, and it hasn't been fixed as of the February 2011 release. However, I implemented your method above `OnNavigateTo`, looped through all the `ListPicker` elements, and it works beautifully. Thanks very much!

Comment: holy cow, absolutely work Tks so much, I have spent a whole day for this until I found ur anwser :D