# Listpicker Selected Item change on generate page (c#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, listpicker

I have a page with generate many element like textblock, listpicker, etc. base on JSON response with C#, not in XAML. so, it is very dynamic page. example (just for Listpicker):

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
     public MainPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
     {
          Generate();
     }

     void Generate()
     {
          stack.Children.Clear(); // in XAML, I just put stackpanel

          //in example I have array of string
           string[] test = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};

           ListPicker list = new ListPicker();

           for (int i = 0; i < test.Count(); i++)
           {
                list.Items.Add(test[i]);
           }
           //I want to keep in fullmode
           list.ExpansionMode = ExpansionMode.FullScreenOnly; 
           sp.Children.Add(list);
     }
```

the problem is, when I select the List item in full mode, the Listpicker selected item not change.

In case [ListPicker SelectedIndex Not Shown Correctly in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801779/listpicker-selectedindex-not-shown-correctly-in-wp7)

I realized my problem is on `OnNavigatedTo`, but I cannot find solution for Listpicker which  created on cs, not XAML first.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I've tried your code seems to work, it only lacks subscription to event: `list.SelectionChanged += list_SelectionChanged;`. Depending on where you put it, it will fire when items are added or not. And what is `sp` - another stackpanel?

Comment: I try to move Generate() to under InitializeComponent(), and it works.. By the way, sp is should be stack (my bad). And thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RezaFauzul if you got the solution to your problem , please post as answer with relevant code.